# R - Error in if (nrow(M) == 2) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, if-statement, arguments

In following code:

```
det<-function(M)
{
    if (nrow(M) == 2)
    {
        return(M[1,1]*M[2,2]-M[1,2]*M[2,1])
    }
    else
    {
      d<-0
      for (i in 1:ncol(M))
      {
        d<-d+(-1)^(i+1)*M[1][i]*det(M[-1,i])
      }
      return(d)
   }
}
```

to execute function I determined

```
 x<-matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3)
```

when execute the function

```
 det(x)
```

I get error:

> Error in if (nrow(M) == 2) { : argument is of length zero

Comment: The `det` function already exists in `R` and does exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a recursive function and the problem is in the following line:

```
d<-d+(-1)^(i+1)*M[1][i]*det(M[-1,i])
```

Here you are using `M[-1, i]` to subset your matrix and R is converting your matrix to a numeric vector (R always converts to the simplest data type when subsetting). You can set the argument `drop=FALSE` to avoid this. See `?"["` and `?drop` for details.

```
x <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
x[-1, 1]
# [1] 2 3
x[-1, 1, drop=FALSE]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    2
# [2,]    3
```

(Please note that your function will fail even when you fix this. In your if statement you access the second column but `M[-1, i]` will always have just one column.)

Comment: Or just to use `NROW` instead of `nrow`.